# Type error in classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a subclass of `Thing` called `Openable`.  When defining the `__init__()` method, I get a

```
type error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jaredbanton8/Documents/things.py", line 57, in <module>
    book1 = Openable("Necronomicon", "book shelf")
  File "/Users/jaredbanton8/Documents/things.py", line 40, in __init__
    super().__init__(name)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'location'
```

In my code, I have included tests for my classes.  I am not sure what is causing this error.  My code is:

```
    class Thing:
        """a class for representing physical objects in a game

        attributes: name (str), location (str)"""
        def __init__(self, name, location):
            """assigns values to attributes"""
            self.name = name
            self.location = location

        def description(self):
            """returns str that describes the state of the object

            str -> str"""
            return str('Nothing special.')
    def test(t):
        """Tests the name, location, and description method of t

        Thing -> None"""
        print(t.name + " (" + t.location + "): " + t.description())


key1 = Thing("golden key", "under door mat")
test(key1)

key2 = Thing("rusty key", "jacket pocket")
test(key2)

    class Openable(Thing):
        """a class for representing those physical objects which can be opened

        inherited attributes: all"""
        def is_open(t):
            """returns a bool whether the object is open or not

            str -> bool"""
            if is_open(t):
                return True
        def __init__(self, name, location, o=0):
            """assigns values to attributes"""
            super().__init__(name)
            super().__init__(location)
            is_open = o

def test_open(o):
    """Tests an attempt to open o

    Openable -> None"""
    print()
    test(o)
    print("Attempting to open the " + o.name + "...")
    if o.try_open():
        print("The " + o.name + " should now be open.")
    else:
        print("The " + o.name + " should now be closed.")
    test(o)

book1 = Openable("Necronomicon", "book shelf")
test_open(book1)

window1 = Openable("side window", "north wall", True)
test_open(window1)
```

Answer (score 8):

You should call `__init__` once with two arguments, not twice with one argument:

```
super().__init__(name, location)
```

Additionally, if you were using Python 2, `super` would also require some arguments:

```
super(Openable, self).__init__(name, location)
```

Comment: The question is tagged python-3.x: the first syntax is valid in Python 3.

Comment: "Additionally, `super` also needs some arguments" - in Python 3, it actually doesn't. They had to do some weird stuff with the compiler to make it work.

Answer (score 7):

`__init__` of `class Thing` needs two arguments. In `__init__` of `class Openable` replace

```
super().__init__(name)
super().__init__(location)
```

with

```
super().__init__(name, location)
```

Code above will work in **Python 3.x**. In **Python 2.x** you need

```
super(Openable, self).__init__(name, location)
```

or

```
Thing.__init__(self, name, location)
```

Function `is_open()` in `class Openable` probably should look like

```
        def is_open():
            return self.isOpen

        def __init__(self, name, location, o=False):
            super().__init__(name, location)
            self.isOpen = o
```

and used

```
if o.is_open():
    print("The " + o.name + " should now be open.")
else:
    print("The " + o.name + " should now be closed.")
```

Comment: I think you meant `Thing.__init__(self, name, location)`, otherwise, it'll give an infinite loop.

Comment: any suggestions on how to fix def is_open(t)?

Comment: @Jared Banton What is the desired behavior of is_open(t)? Can you give an example?

Comment: @kvorobiev i want to return a boolean attribute called is_open that represents whether or not the object is open, because right now, I am returned an attribute error 'Openable' object has no attribute 'try_open'